# Shared pointers to vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, collections, shared-ptr

Please excuse the simple question, but I'm having trouble understanding pointers to collections.

Imagine that I have this vector of bytes:

```
vector<uint8_t> n;
```

I want to store this in a shared pointer. Why do I need the address-of (&) operator?

```
shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>> m(&n);
```

I would think that the constructor would take `n`. But I also think that I have a deep misconception about what is going on here :)

Comment: The argument to the constructor is supposed to be a pointer.

Comment: I don't want to be that guy but...I think you meant miscomprehension. Unless you're genuinely scared :p (I'll remove this comment very shortly)

Comment: mis·ap·pre·hen·sion : false impression, a false impression or incorrect understanding, especially of the nature of a situation or somebody's intentions.
(I changed it to miscomprehension anyway though, as I'm not great with English).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to store this in a shared pointer.

No you don't. A shared pointer is for managing a dynamic object that needs to be deleted; this vector wasn't created with `new`, so can't be managed by a (normal) shared pointer. The pointer would attempt to delete it, causing mayhem.

You want to create the vector dynamically so that `shared_ptr` can manage it correctly:

```
auto m = make_shared<vector<uint8_t>>();
```

> Why do I need the address-of (&) operator?

Because shared pointers are (usually) used to manage objects created with `new`, and `new` gives a pointer; so `shared_ptr` has a constructor taking a pointer argument. However, it's usually better to use the `make_shared` function demonstrated above, rather than messing around with `new` yourself.

Comment: "usually"? Is there a legitimate use for `shared_ptr` with objects not allocated with `new`?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, if you provide a deleter that does something other than `delete`.